# MoinMoin on help.ubuntu.com broken? JS console shows 404 for common.js

Tags: ubuntu-wiki, ubuntu-website

I'm not sure if this is just me, or if this is an actual problem. Looking at the JS console in Chrome/Chromium, I see a 404 for https://help.ubuntu.com/moin_static193/common/js/common.js and a missing JS function actionMenuInit():

```
![Failed to load common.js][1]
```

I tried this in incognito mode with cache and extensions disabled and get the same error, so I'm reasonably sure it isn't me.

Answer (score 1):

The [contact us](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us://) page on ubuntu.com has this:

> **Web feedback**
>
> If you have suggestions or corrections for ubuntu.com or canonical.com, email us at webmaster@ubuntu.com or webmaster@canonical.com.

A mail to webmaster@ubuntu.com is most likely to be the quickest method to get this fixed.

Comment: Elsewhere, IRC is described as the preferred method.  I posted a link to this in the #ubuntu-website channel.